# Add paragraph domains to media View

Tags: views, 8, media, domain-access, paragraphs

I'm using [media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) and [domain](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) modules.
Nodes are assigned to multiple domains and there are image fields that link to media images on those nodes.
Some content types also use paragraphs and these paragraphs hold their own image fields, referencing media images.

The media view (/admin/content/media) provides some nice information out of the box and I have added a relationship to the image field used on nodes which allows me to add a field for Affiliate domains for the nodes that hold these images. This adds a list of domains for each media image (used on nodes) to the media View.

I need to display the same information for the image fields used in paragraphs. I can add a relationship to these paragraph image fields but that doesn't add an available field that would allow me to display the domains these paragraphs are assigned to. I guess that has to do with config entities not mixing very well with the domain module and Views.

What would the best way to add this field to the media view? A custom field handler seems to be the best bet but it seems that a query is needed to get the domains to which each node (holding a paragraph that holds an image field) is assigned to.

What's the best strategy to get this custom "computed" field into my view?

Answer (score 0):

A newly developed module, [Media View Addons](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_view_addons), provides just that.